# Is there a Bash command or series of commands which will identify and remove replicated directories?

Tags: replication

I'm working on a developing a script which will, inside of a directory, verify the existence of a sub-directory, then locate and delete replicated copies in the same directory. For example:

A directory has the following sub-directory added:

```
FLDR6544_8765
```

Other copies of the folder are replicated, such as:

```
FLDR6544_8765-0
FLDR6544_8765-1
FLDR6544_8765-2
```

Is there a command or scripted series of commands which will verify the existence of the original folder (in the example `FLDR6544_8765`), then remove the replicated folders (`FLDR6544_8765-0`, `FLDR6544_8765-1`, `FLDR6544_8765-2`)

I can use

```
find -type d -name "-0" exec rm -r {} \; -prune
```

to find the directories with the replicated endings (-0, -1, etc), but that doesn't ensure the original file exists before deleting the replicated copies.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you might have!

Comment: Welcome, you say * - which will verify the existence of the original folder -  *. How do you know which folder name look for existence? It means that you find the replicates, and from there you get the name of the original?

Comment: Thanks for your response! The original file and replicated duplicates are all listed together as follows:
FLDR6544_8765
FLDR6544_8765-0
FLDR6544_8765-1
FLDR6544_8765-2

I need to develop a script which will recognize the sequence, save the original (or one of the duplicates if the original is no longer in the folder) and delete the duplicates.

Comment: Provide clarification? Do you want to remove folders which are exact replicas of one folder? What about partial replicas (for example, DirA has 50 files, and DirB has 25 files--but all 25 files are also in DirA))? Or do you just want to de-duplicate your files, such that among all the folders, you have only one copy of each unique file? Or something else?